# Setting select element as disabled on form submission (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a php loop that echos multiple `<select>` elements as part of an online ordering system where the user can select the quantity of a certain item.

The button that executes the form runs a php script that inserts the values into my database, however, I need to be able to ignore the values that are equal to "0".

By creating an onClick event (JS function) on the submit button, I execute this code:

```
$('#quantityForm').find(':select').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "0"){
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
})
```

Everything seems to work fine except the code that sets the `<select>` element as disabled, as my php script attempts to get all of the "0" values.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Additional code:

```
<form id="quantityForm" method="get">
    <?php get_items($example); ?>
    <button onClick="checkQuantity()" id='basket' type='submit' name='submit'><i class='fas fa-shopping-basket'></i></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to disable the select, or the option that has a value of 0?  Because the select will only have a value of 0 once that option is selected

Comment: `:select` isn't a thing.  `select` is.  it's an exact tag name.  `:input` is a jquery pseudo selector for all types of form inputs.

Comment: @Taplar I am wanting to disable the select so the form does not submit it to my php script. 0 is selected by default :)

Comment: Ahh, ok, so yeah.   Change `:select` to `select`

Comment: You should remove the select's `name` attribute when the option with `value="0"` is selected, that way your form will ignore the select input.

Comment: you should use prop instead of attr()
cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: @Taplar That fixed it! Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#quantityForm')
    //find all the select elements in the form
    .find('select')
    //filter and return only those that have a value of 0
    .filter(function(){
        return this.value === '0';
    })
    //make them disabled
    .prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the select's `name` attribute when the option with `value="0"` is selected, that way your form will ignore the select input.

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 0) {
        $(this).attr('name', '');
    }
    else {
        $(this).attr('name', '<name>');
    }
});
```

Comment: The user wants it disabled on page load, and not be changable.